# Jquery: move elements from a list to another

Tags: jquery, list

Well, i have 2 lists .What i need to do is whenever i click an element it will move from a list to another.
Successfully, my code do this, but just 1 time. if the element is moved i can't move it back.
I really don't know what to do. Can you guys help me?( sorry for the bad code :)) )

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list1 .item').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $('#list2').append("<option class='item' >" +this.text + "</option>");
        $(this).remove();
});

    $('#list2 .item').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $('#list1').append("<option class='item' >" +this.text + "</option>" );
        $(this).remove();
});

});
```

And html

```
<body>
    <div id="tabela1">
        <select size='5' id='list1'>
            <option class='item' >OB1</option>
            <option class='item' >OB2</option>
            <option class='item' >OB3</option>
            <option class='item' >OB4</option>
            <option class='item' >OB5</option>
            <option class='item' >OB6</option>
            <option class='item' >OB7</option>
            <option class='item' >OB8</option>
            <option class='item' >OB9</option>
            <option class='item' >OB10</option>
            <option class='item' >OB11</option>
            <option class='item' >OB12</option>

        </select>

    <div id="tabela2">
        <select size="5" id='list2'>
        <option class='item' >O</option>
        </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can actually append this directly. Since DOM nodes are unique it will be moved automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `click` on `<option>` it is not supported in many browsers...notably IE and Safari. Same for other events as well as hide

Use change event on the `<select>` and simply `append()` the selected option to the other `<select>`

```js
var $selects = $('#list1, #list2').on('change', function() {
  // "this" is the select element that was changed
  $selects.not(this).append($(this).find(':selected'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabela1">
  <select size='5' id='list1'>
    <option class='item'>OB1</option>
    <option class='item'>OB2</option>
    <option class='item'>OB3</option>
    <option class='item'>OB4</option>
    <option class='item'>OB5</option>
    <option class='item'>OB6</option>
    <option class='item'>OB7</option>
    <option class='item'>OB8</option>
    <option class='item'>OB9</option>
    <option class='item'>OB10</option>
    <option class='item'>OB11</option>
    <option class='item'>OB12</option>

  </select>
</div>
<div id="tabela2">
  <select size="5" id='list2'>
    <option class='item'>O</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Working code

```
$('body').on('click', '#list1 .item', function(event){
    $(this).appendTo('#list2') // “this” is the clicked element
})

$('body').on('click', '#list2 .item', function(event){
    $(this).appendTo('#list1') // “this” is the clicked element
})
```

## Why your solution doesn’t work

When you do `$('#list1 .item').on('click'`, jQuery will seek all elements that *currently* match your selector and add the event listener to them. If you now move the element to the other list, it will retain its original event listener, which moves it to the second list, even though it *now* isn’t targeted by `#list1 .item` anymore. What causes the problem is that it doesn’t get the event handler for `#list2 .item`, either, since the element wasn’t selected by that expression when the event listener was attached.

## Why my proposed solution works

The code above doesn’t bind the event listeners on the elements themselves, but on some parent, which doesn’t move. It relies on the click event’s *bubbling up the DOM*. That is, the event doesn’t only ask the element which was actually clicked if it listens for the event, but also each of its parents. We can use this to have the parents, e.g. `body`, listen for the event and see *at the time the event is created*, i.e. when you click the list entry, *by selector(s)* it is targeted. We can then use this information to trigger the appropriate JS.

Worth a read: http://api.jquery.com/on/, especially the section about ”Delegated elements”